# "Two classes have the same XML type name" when returning XML response in Quarkus

Tags: xml, cxf, quarkus, resteasy

Quarkus version - 3.2.0.Final

XCF version - 2.2.2 (tried also 5.2.0)

Example Quarkus REST resource that returns XML response:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public MyResponse<MyEntity> serviceThatReturnsXml() {
  // return MyResponse instance
}
```

The MyResponse class:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TagName")
public class MyResponse<T> {
  @XmlElement(name = "ChildTagName")
  private List<T> items;
}
```

Error when calling the REST resource:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}EndpointReferenceType". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at jakarta.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType
        at public org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ObjectFactory.createEndpointReferenceType()
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ObjectFactory
        at protected java.util.List org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MetadataType.any
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MetadataType

    at io.quarkus.jaxb.runtime.JaxbContextProducer.createJAXBContext(JaxbContextProducer.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.jaxb.runtime.JaxbContextProducer_ClientProxy.createJAXBContext(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jaxb.runtime.JAXBContextContextResolver.getContext(JAXBContextContextResolver.java:27)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jaxb.runtime.JAXBContextContextResolver.getContext(JAXBContextContextResolver.java:13)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jaxb.runtime.serialisers.ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.getMarshall(ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jaxb.runtime.serialisers.ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.marshal(ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.jaxb.runtime.serialisers.ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.writeResponse(ServerJaxbMessageBodyWriter.java:51)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.ServerSerialisers.invokeWriter(ServerSerialisers.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.serialization.FixedEntityWriter.write(FixedEntityWriter.java:28)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResponseWriterHandler.handle(ResponseWriterHandler.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:147)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

pom.xml dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-cxf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Tried the following in application.yaml but no effect.

```yaml
quarkus:
  jaxb:
    exclude-classes: org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType
    validate-jaxb-context: false
```

Tried to exclude the second

```yaml
quarkus:
  jaxb:
    exclude-classes: jakarta.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
    validate-jaxb-context: false
```

Now response is returned but the main tag includes a lot of unused xmlns attributes:

```xml
<TagName xmlns:ns2="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:ns3="http://api.nef.co.adapter.model.esb.p4.org" 
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy" 
xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:ns6="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" 
xmlns:ns7="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing" 
xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:ns10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:ns11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:ns12="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:ns13="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:ns14="http://base.api.nef.co.adapter.model.esb.p4.org" 
xmlns:ns15="http://esb.p4.org" 
xmlns:ns16="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration" 
xmlns:ns17="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"/>
```

CXF extension cannot be removed because it's used in another pieces of code.

How to solve dependency conflict to get rid of this error?

Comment: this is may be a bug, I saw something similar at https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/4603 , try to open an issue in github please.